# Understanding the output of ClearNLP

Tags: netbeans, nlp

I am using ClearNLP as a semantic labeler but I have some questions:

1. Can I change the output to a tree view that shows the semantic dependencies?
2. What does Sheads="**2:A0=PAG**" mean? I could not understand the semantic output in a sentence such: I have a new employee. He has studied computer science and has developed a lot of programs; he is qualified to be manager. add him in the appropriate table.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the output of the clearnlp suite and paste it in this online visualization tool that will draw it: http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~choi/clearnlp/demo/demo.html

About your second question, `A0` refers to the first slot in the SRL of the verb.